# How to stop an android application from adb without force-stop or root?

Tags: android, adb

I need to kill an activity (or the whole package) using adb without having root permissions (this rules out kill), while ensuring that the activity can receive an intent afterwards (this rules out force stop).

Edit: I tried kill and am kill (from shell). The former requires root and the latter does not reliably kill the activity that I need to be killed.

Answer (score 3):

```
run-as <package-name> kill <pid>
```

Note that `run-as` is only supported for apps that are signed with debug keys.

Answer (score 1):

I think, kill or stop are not the appropriate words in this situation. If all you want is to leave that application, you can use `adb shell input keyevent <KeyEvent.KEYCODE_XX>` to emulate key press events. For e.g., following is for Home button:

```
adb shell input keyevent 3
```

And following is for Back key:

```
adb shell input keyevent 4
```

See [KeyEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) for full list of codes.